# New robot framework function that uses webdriver

Tags: python, webdriver, robotframework

I have many tests and own functions in RF but till now I didn't need functions that uses `webdriver` cause all my functions only return value.

Now I need to make a function that paste some text in one not write it.
How can I implement it into my tests ?

I mean I do not know how to connect that function with `webdriver` that RF creates.

**My own lib:**
`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import os
from robot.errors import ExecutionFailed
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import logger
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_ID_from_URL(url):
    x = url.split('names/')[-1]
    x = x.split('/')
    return x[0]

def random_number():
    random_num = random.randint(100000, 9000000)  # random integer in range
    return random_num


def return_list(input_text):
    x = input_text.split(';')
    return x

.
.
.

def paste(locator, text):
    os.system("echo %s| clip" % text.strip())
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

I need help with that paste function.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that this has nothing to do with Robot Framework but is a pure Python/Webdriver issue. So removing the Robot Framework tag is appropriate. Is this a known typo? `ellement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')` i.e should be `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')`

Comment: Yes just missclick.
But any solution for my problem ?
I think that RF tah was appropriate cause if I use selenium I wouldn't need help. But in RF I don't know how to connect to webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current instance of webdriver by using the method `_current_browser`. You can call that method by first getting the current instance of the selenium library.

Example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def paste(xpath, text):
    se2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("Selenium2Library")
    driver = se2lib._current_browser()
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did it but i use  `browser = s2l._browser`
Now I just need to wait for element to be visible cause I am getting error.